# how to write parallel prefix sum in c#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, prefix-sum

I want to write a Parallel prefix sum in c#. i used this algorithm:

```
initial condition: list of n >= 1 elements stored in A[0...(n-1)]
final condition: each element A[i] contains A[0]+A[1]+...+A[i]
begin
  spawn (p1,p2,...,p(n-1))
  foe all pi where 1 <= i <= n-1 do
    for j←0 to ⌈logn⌉-1 do
      if i - 2^j >= 0 then
        A[i] ← A[i] + A[i - 2^j]
      end if
    end for
  end for
end
```

and my final code in c# is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MPI;

namespace prefixsum3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] A = new int[] { 4, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3 };
            using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
            {
                Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;
                int size, rank, n, i;
                size = comm.Size;
                i = comm.Rank + 1;
                n = A.Length;
                int[] B = new int[10];
                for (int j = 0; j <= (Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(n))) - 1; j++)
                {
                    int t = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, j));
                    if ( i - t >= 0)
                    {
                        B[i] = A[i] + A[i - t];
                    }
                    comm.Barrier();
                    A[i] = B[i];
                    comm.Barrier();
                }
                if (comm.Rank == 0)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(A[z].ToString() + ",");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the wright output should be: [4,7,15,17,26,27,30,35,41,44]
but my output code is: [4,7,8,2,9,1,3,5,6,3]
is any one know what is wrong with my code?
EDIT:
i found every processors see array A locally. now the problem is how to define array A Globally that all processors see one array?

Comment: The C# code does not use the same algorithm as the original piece as far as I can tell. The first piece of code uses 2 loops (foe, for: maybe typo?) while the C# snippet only has one loop implemented.

Comment: the first for tell that all processors should run the following code. in my code `using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))` part will run all processors in parallel.

Comment: Can the error be because you're using a new array instead of changing the values in the old one? So in the if-statement you should write "A[i] += A[i - t]" or without shorthand "A[i] = A[i] + A[i - t]" ?

Comment: i do not think it is a problem. i used tow array because processors do not run in same speed, and it`s possible in one stage a processor read and change array before other processors read the array.

Answer (score 0):

As for correctness the logarithm in the original algorithm is to the base 2, this is your error (or one of them).

Regarding efficiency, you didn't understand correctly the double buffer algorithm: you're supposed to write in B[i], synchronize, then swap the A and B arrays before the next iteration. You don't need two barriers or A[i] = B[i]. However you must do B[i] = A[i] when t is greater or equal to i.

Finally Math.Pow is inefficient, you should better start with t = 1 then multiply it by 2 on every iteration (t <<= 1). Anyway you should simply use the following loop that is faster and fixes the previously mentioned error (you no longer need the log):

```
for (int t = 1; t < n; t <<= 1)
```

Comment: i don`t think it is a problem. i found the problem : every node see array A locally. how can i make the array globally which all processors see one array?